# Is there a way to drag many nodes inside the graph?

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

Hello I am using currently the sigma.plugins.dragNodes to drag nodes individually. Has anyone used it to drag multiple nodes passing it in a single object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this version of the drag Node plugin, it handles selection of multiple nodes. This plugin is under MIT license.

https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js/tree/linkurious-version/plugins/sigma.plugins.dragNodes

PS: I am currently working for Linkurious ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just found this project on github:

https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/issues/516

that has changed the plugin in a way to accept movement of multiple nodes at once in the graph. Though I did not yet managed to run it, I will post some demo once I manage it. cheers